# .Call mdsplib - METAR - Buffer Overflow - what does this valgrind output mean?

Tags: c, r, memory, memory-management, valgrind

I'm developping a package to connect R with [mdsplib](http://limulus.net/mdsplib/), in order to parse METAR reports. It is available here: https://github.com/jwijffels/RMETAR and you can install it in R with.

```
require(devtools)
install_github("RMETAR", "jwijffels", subdir="/pkg")
```

The R package basically uses .Call to execute a C function called DcdMETAR which is provided in mdsplib. So far so good. This works in 99.99% of the METAR cases. With some strange METAR codes, I get a crash stating: *** buffer overflow detected ***. 
Below is a reproducible example.

```
require(RMETAR)
givesbufferoverflow <- c(
  "MPTO 270000Z 00000KT 9999 FEW008SCT018CB BKN090 27/24 Q1010 RETSRA RWY DAMP",
  "GBYD 271100Z 09004KT 9999 BKN012?FEW018CB SCT120 29/24 Q1013 CB(NW-W)",
  "HKKI 262300Z 00000KT 9999 FEW019=BKN080 20/19 Q1017")
decodemetar(givesbufferoverflow[1])
```

So what to do? I run valgrind as stated in [R-ext](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Using-valgrind). The above R code is put into a file called i_hate_memory_management.R and I run:

```
R -d "valgrind --tool=memcheck --leak-check=full" --vanilla < i_hate_memory_management.R
```

Now this gives me the following message:
Can someone help me out in identifying what this message means. It seems to be a memory usage problem with character strings but what does it really mean and how can I solve this issue?

```
> require(RMETAR)
Loading required package: RMETAR
> givesbufferoverflow <- c(
+   "MPTO 270000Z 00000KT 9999 FEW008SCT018CB BKN090 27/24 Q1010 RETSRA RWY DAMP",
+   "GBYD 271100Z 09004KT 9999 BKN012?FEW018CB SCT120 29/24 Q1013 CB(NW-W)",
+   "HKKI 262300Z 00000KT 9999 FEW019=BKN080 20/19 Q1017")
> decodemetar(givesbufferoverflow[1])
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R terminated
======= Backtrace: =========
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__fortify_fail+0x37)[0x571d817]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x109710)[0x571c710]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x1089f6)[0x571b9f6]
/home/janw/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RMETAR/libs/RMETAR.so(+0xa589)[0x105a9589]
/home/janw/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RMETAR/libs/RMETAR.so(+0xa873)[0x105a9873]
/home/janw/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RMETAR/libs/RMETAR.so(DcdMETAR+0x1503)[0x105ab233]
/home/janw/R/x86_64-pc-linux-gnu-library/2.15/RMETAR/libs/RMETAR.so(decodeMETAR+0x279)[0x105a7669]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0xb9f08)[0x4eebf08]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_eval+0x73d)[0x4f25bcd]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0xf57a0)[0x4f277a0]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_eval+0x51f)[0x4f259af]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0xf5920)[0x4f27920]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_eval+0x51f)[0x4f259af]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_applyClosure+0x34d)[0x4f28e0d]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_eval+0x400)[0x4f25890]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(Rf_ReplIteration+0x1e3)[0x4f61fa3]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(+0x130230)[0x4f62230]
/usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so(run_Rmainloop+0x5a)[0x4f622ca]
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R(main+0x1b)[0x40078b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xed)[0x563476d]
/usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R[0x4007bd]
======= Memory map: ========
00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6948377                            /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 08:05 6948377                            /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 6948377                            /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
04000000-04022000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489457                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
04022000-04023000 rw-s 00000000 08:05 4456681                            /tmp/vgdb-pipe-shared-mem-vgdb-5873-by-janw-on-???
04023000-04026000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
04026000-04027000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 11927559                           /SYSV00000000 (deleted)
04027000-04028000 rw-s 00000000 00:04 5046278                            /SYSV00510510 (deleted)
04028000-04029000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
04029000-04030000 r--s 00000000 08:05 6964289                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
04030000-04031000 r--p 00000000 08:05 9581751                            /usr/share/R/share/locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/R.mo
04031000-04033000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
04046000-0404e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
04222000-04223000 r--p 00022000 08:05 10489457                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
04223000-04225000 rw-p 00023000 08:05 10489457                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
04225000-04226000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
04a25000-04a26000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6698284                            /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
04a26000-04c25000 ---p 00001000 08:05 6698284                            /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
04c25000-04c26000 r--p 00000000 08:05 6698284                            /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
04c26000-04c27000 rw-p 00001000 08:05 6698284                            /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_core-amd64-linux.so
04c27000-04c31000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6698333                            /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
04c31000-04e30000 ---p 0000a000 08:05 6698333                            /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
04e30000-04e31000 r--p 00009000 08:05 6698333                            /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
04e31000-04e32000 rw-p 0000a000 08:05 6698333                            /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so
04e32000-050f5000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 7083949                            /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so
050f5000-052f5000 ---p 002c3000 08:05 7083949                            /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so
052f5000-052fb000 r--p 002c3000 08:05 7083949                            /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so
052fb000-0530b000 rw-p 002c9000 08:05 7083949                            /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so
0530b000-053f6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
053f6000-0540e000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10485801                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
0540e000-0560d000 ---p 00018000 08:05 10485801                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
0560d000-0560e000 r--p 00017000 08:05 10485801                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
0560e000-0560f000 rw-p 00018000 08:05 10485801                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
0560f000-05613000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
05613000-057c8000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10485799                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
057c8000-059c7000 ---p 001b5000 08:05 10485799                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
059c7000-059cb000 r--p 001b4000 08:05 10485799                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
059cb000-059cd000 rw-p 001b8000 08:05 10485799                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
059cd000-059d2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
059d2000-06c54000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6815808                            /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0
06c54000-06e54000 ---p 01282000 08:05 6815808                            /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0
06e54000-06e5b000 r--p 01282000 08:05 6815808                            /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0
06e5b000-06e69000 rw-p 01289000 08:05 6815808                            /usr/lib/openblas-base/libopenblas.so.0
06e69000-06e71000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
06e71000-06f6c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10486670                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
06f6c000-0716b000 ---p 000fb000 08:05 10486670                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
0716b000-0716c000 r--p 000fa000 08:05 10486670                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
0716c000-0716d000 rw-p 000fb000 08:05 10486670                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
0716d000-071a6000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489427                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.2
071a6000-073a6000 ---p 00039000 08:05 10489427                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.2
073a6000-073a8000 r--p 00039000 08:05 10489427                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.2
073a8000-073ae000 rw-p 0003b000 08:05 10489427                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.2
073ae000-073af000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
073af000-073eb000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489417                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1
073eb000-075ea000 ---p 0003c000 08:05 10489417                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1
075ea000-075eb000 r--p 0003b000 08:05 10489417                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1
075eb000-075ec000 rw-p 0003c000 08:05 10489417                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.12.1
075ec000-0760d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6692207                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
0760d000-0780c000 ---p 00021000 08:05 6692207                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
0780c000-0780d000 r--p 00020000 08:05 6692207                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
0780d000-0780e000 rw-p 00021000 08:05 6692207                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5.0.0
0780e000-0781d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489343                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
0781d000-07a1c000 ---p 0000f000 08:05 10489343                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
07a1c000-07a1d000 r--p 0000e000 08:05 10489343                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
07a1d000-07a1e000 rw-p 0000f000 08:05 10489343                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbz2.so.1.0.4
07a1e000-07a34000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489455                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
07a34000-07c33000 ---p 00016000 08:05 10489455                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
07c33000-07c34000 r--p 00015000 08:05 10489455                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
07c34000-07c35000 rw-p 00016000 08:05 10489455                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
07c35000-07c3c000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10485803                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
07c3c000-07e3b000 ---p 00007000 08:05 10485803                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
07e3b000-07e3c000 r--p 00006000 08:05 10485803                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
07e3c000-07e3d000 rw-p 00007000 08:05 10485803                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
07e3d000-07e3f000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10485798                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
07e3f000-0803f000 ---p 00002000 08:05 10485798                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
0803f000-08040000 r--p 00002000 08:05 10485798                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
08040000-08041000 rw-p 00003000 08:05 10485798                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.15.so
08041000-0804e000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6692082                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
0804e000-0824d000 ---p 0000d000 08:05 6692082                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
0824d000-0824e000 r--p 0000c000 08:05 6692082                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
0824e000-0824f000 rw-p 0000d000 08:05 6692082                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgomp.so.1.0.0
0824f000-08271000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489441                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
08271000-08471000 ---p 00022000 08:05 10489441                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
08471000-08475000 r--p 00022000 08:05 10489441                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
08475000-08476000 rw-p 00026000 08:05 10489441                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5.9
08476000-08876000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
08876000-08f59000 r--p 00000000 08:05 6691142                            /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
08f59000-09359000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
09359000-09361000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489326                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
09361000-09560000 ---p 00008000 08:05 10489326                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
09560000-09561000 r--p 00007000 08:05 10489326                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
09561000-09562000 rw-p 00008000 08:05 10489326                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.15.so
09562000-09579000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489462                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
09579000-09778000 ---p 00017000 08:05 10489462                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
09778000-09779000 r--p 00016000 08:05 10489462                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
09779000-0977a000 rw-p 00017000 08:05 10489462                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.15.so
0977a000-0977c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0977c000-09786000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10485832                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
09786000-09986000 ---p 0000a000 08:05 10485832                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
09986000-09987000 r--p 0000a000 08:05 10485832                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
09987000-09988000 rw-p 0000b000 08:05 10485832                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.15.so
09988000-09994000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 10489325                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
09994000-09b93000 ---p 0000c000 08:05 10489325                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
09b93000-09b94000 r--p 0000b000 08:05 10489325                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
09b94000-09b95000 rw-p 0000c000 08:05 10489325                           /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.15.so
09b95000-09f95000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
09f95000-09f9d000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9710069                            /usr/lib/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so
09f9d000-0a19c000 ---p 00008000 08:05 9710069                            /usr/lib/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so
0a19c000-0a19d000 r--p 00007000 08:05 9710069                            /usr/lib/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so
0a19d000-0a19e000 rw-p 00008000 08:05 9710069                            /usr/lib/R/library/methods/libs/methods.so
0a393000-0c393000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0c393000-0cb93000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
0cb93000-0cb95000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6964391                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
0cb95000-0cd94000 ---p 00002000 08:05 6964391                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
0cd94000-0cd95000 r--p 00001000 08:05 6964391                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
0cd95000-0cd96000 rw-p 00002000 08:05 6964391                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/ISO8859-1.so
0cd96000-0d996000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
0d996000-0d9bd000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9709626                            /usr/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so
0d9bd000-0dbbd000 ---p 00027000 08:05 9709626                            /usr/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so
0dbbd000-0dbbe000 r--p 00027000 08:05 9709626                            /usr/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so
0dbbe000-0dbbf000 rw-p 00028000 08:05 9709626                            /usr/lib/R/library/grDevices/libs/grDevices.so
0dbbf000-0ebbf000 rwxp 00000000 00:00 0 
0ebbf000-0ec43000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9701761                            /usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so
0ec43000-0ee42000 ---p 00084000 08:05 9701761                            /usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so
0ee42000-0ee44000 r--p 00083000 08:05 9701761                            /usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so
0ee44000-0ee46000 rw-p 00085000 08:05 9701761                            /usr/lib/R/library/stats/libs/stats.so
0ee46000-0f72b000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 9571291                            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3gf.0
0f72b000-0f92a000 ---p 008e5000 08:05 9571291                            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3gf.0
0f92a000-0f92b000 r--p 008e4000 08:05 9571291                            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3gf.0
0f92b000-0f92f000 rw-p 008e5000 08:05 9571291                            /usr/lib/lapack/liblapack.so.3gf.0
0f92f000-0fa3c000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0 
0fa3c000-0fb50000 r-xp 00000000 08:05 6691211                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
0fb50000-0fd50000 ---p 00114000 08:05 6691211                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0
0fd50000-0fd51000 r--p 00114000 08:05 6691211                            /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgfortran.so.3.0.0==5873== 
==5873== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5873==     in use at exit: 28,551,157 bytes in 12,623 blocks
==5873==   total heap usage: 31,354 allocs, 18,731 frees, 48,823,198 bytes allocated
==5873== 
==5873== 300 (60 direct, 240 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 101 of 1,544
==5873==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5873==    by 0x57185A4: nss_parse_service_list (nsswitch.c:678)
==5873==    by 0x5719065: __nss_database_lookup (nsswitch.c:175)
==5873==    by 0x935D623: ???
==5873==    by 0x56D1C0C: getpwuid_r@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (getXXbyYY_r.c:256)
==5873==    by 0x56D1502: getpwuid (getXXbyYY.c:117)
==5873==    by 0x4F94108: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F18930: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F25609: Rf_eval (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F28E0C: Rf_applyClosure (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F21431: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F25609: Rf_eval (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873== 
==5873== 300 (60 direct, 240 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 102 of 1,544
==5873==    at 0x4C2B6CD: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==5873==    by 0x57185A4: nss_parse_service_list (nsswitch.c:678)
==5873==    by 0x5719065: __nss_database_lookup (nsswitch.c:175)
==5873==    by 0x935B3BB: ???
==5873==    by 0x56D022C: getgrgid_r@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (getXXbyYY_r.c:256)
==5873==    by 0x56CF972: getgrgid (getXXbyYY.c:117)
==5873==    by 0x4F94134: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F18930: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F25609: Rf_eval (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F28E0C: Rf_applyClosure (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F21431: ??? (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873==    by 0x4F25609: Rf_eval (in /usr/lib/R/lib/libR.so)
==5873== 
==5873== LEAK SUMMARY:
==5873==    definitely lost: 120 bytes in 2 blocks
==5873==    indirectly lost: 480 bytes in 20 blocks
==5873==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5873==    still reachable: 28,550,557 bytes in 12,601 blocks
==5873==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5873== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==5873== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-reachable=yes
==5873== 
==5873== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5873== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==5873== ERROR SUMMARY: 421 errors from 10 contexts (suppressed: 2 from 2)
Aborted (core dumped)
```

Comment: Congratulations, now we know how to attract the wrath of C community at large.

Comment: Did you try setting `DEBUGZZ` to true?

Comment: DEBUGZZ. In dcdmetar.c. Not yet, will have a look. Thanks.

Comment: DcdMETAR: Returned from InitDcdMETAR
DcdMETAR: Before start of tokenizing, string = MPTO 270000Z 00000KT 9999 FEW008SCT018CB BKN090 27/24 Q1010 RETSRA RWY DAMP
DcdMETAR: token[0] = MPTO
*** buffer overflow detected ***: /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R terminated

Comment: Why all the negative waves? Just wondering.

Comment: @Jim http://www.theguardian.com/education/2011/oct/03/research-demonstrates-language-affects-behaviour http://stackoverflow.com/posts/18103217/revisions

Comment: Wow- from -11 to -5 in an hour!  What is this: Slashdot moderation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right. I tracked down the bug with some printf statements.
Basically I had to replace the following code in parseCldData of dcdmetar.c of the mdsplib library

from

```
strncpy(Mptr->cldTypHgt[next].other_cld_phenom,token+6, (strlen(token)-6));
```

to

```
strncpy(Mptr->cldTypHgt[next].other_cld_phenom,token+6, min(4, (strlen(token)-6)));
```

as Mptr->cldTypHgt[next].other_cld_phenom seemed to be of type **char** other_cld_phenom[**4**];
And in my example METAR cases, the cloud phenomena where larger than 6 characters wide.
Just send the bug to the author of mdsplib.

Now, when looking back at the valgrind output, this wasn't at all showing the cause of the problem. I'm wondering if there exists better ways to debug than using printf.